# Radio checked does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just check if the radio checked button checked or not but it's not show alert.

My code is here:

**js code:**

```
var dayshift=document.getElementsByName("dayshift");
var weekshift=document.getElementsByName("weekshift");

if(dayshift.checked && weekshift.checked)
{
  alert("shift");
}
```

My html code:

**html code:**

```
<input type="radio" name="dayshift" value="Day" checked/> 
<input type="radio" name="dayshift" value="Night"/> 
<input type="radio"  name="weekshift" value="Weekday" checked/> 
<input type="radio"  name="weekshift" value="Weekend" />
```

Comment: [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns the live node list! you can't perform a direct check on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getElementsByName` returns array. you can access your element by indexing `dayshift[0]` for first element

```js
var dayshift = document.getElementsByName("dayshift");
var weekshift = document.getElementsByName("weekshift");

if (dayshift[0].checked && weekshift[0].checked) {
  console.log("shift");
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="dayshift" value="Day" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="dayshift" value="Night" />
<input type="radio" name="weekshift" value="Weekday" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="weekshift" value="Weekend" />
```

Comment: Thanks Jyothi Babu Araji. It's really worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$("input[name=dayshift]").prop("checked", true);
```

so if you do in condition

```
if($("input[name=dayshift]").prop("checked", true)){
     alert("checked/shifted");
}
```